Snowflake- How to remove $ label while loading data from a stage into a table
I used below insert command to load data from a internal stage into a table
create or replace table corps_table as 
select $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8 from @~/staged;

but the label '$' appear in the corps_table above to the actual columns.
so how to remove the $ label and only to include actual column names in the table?

Create your table first and then use a COPY INTO command, instead.

Create your table first with appropriate column names and use INSERT INTO

or provide a column alias while reading the data from stage.
